# Time series prediction of daily data of a month using ARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am working with 30 days (monthly) per cycle and thus have approximately 2 cycles in my historical dataset.

`R` script is,

```
library(forecast)
value <- c(117.2 , 224.2 , 258.0 , 292.1 , 400.1 , 509.9 , 626.8 , 722.9 , 826.1 , 883.6,916.6, 1032.1, 1151.2, 1273.4 ,1391.8, 1499.2, 1532.5 ,1565.9 ,1690.9, 1813.6,1961.4 ,2102.8 ,2208.2, 2256.8, 2290.8 ,2413.7, 2569.4 ,2730.3, 2882.9 ,2977.5, 117.2 , 224.2 , 258.0 , 292.1 , 400.1 , 509.9 , 626.8 , 722.9 , 826.1 , 883.6,916.6, 1032.1, 1151.2, 1273.4 ,1391.8, 1499.2, 1532.5 ,1565.9 ,1690.9, 1813.6,1961.4 ,2102.8 ,2208.2, 2256.8, 2290.8 ,2413.7, 2569.4 ,2730.3, 2882.9 ,2977.5)

sensor<-ts(value,frequency=30)#daily data of month,here only 2 month's data
fit <- auto.arima(sensor)
LH.pred<-predict(fit,n.ahead=30)
plot(sensor,ylim=c(0,4000),xlim=c(0,5),type="o", lwd="1")
lines(LH.pred$pred,col="red",type="o",lwd="1")
grid()
```

The resulting graph is 
[image: prediction graph]

But I am not satisfied with the prediction. Is there any way to make the prediction look similar to the value trends preceding it (see graph)?

Comment: It looks like your data is cumulative over the month and reset at the beginning of the month, is that so? If so, you might get a better result by forecasting the original (not yet summed) data and summing/resetting the forecast as appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are asking a lot of `auto.arima()` to find a model using only two months of data. At least help it out a little by suggesting a seasonal difference. Further, don't use `predict`. The `forecast` function is much nicer.

For reasons why `forecast()` is "nicer", see the [Journal of Statistical Software of July 2008](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i03/paper), in particular section 4.4:

> The forecast() function is generic and has S3 methods for a wide range
>   of time series models. It computes point forecasts and prediction
>   intervals from the time series model. Methods exist for models fitted
>   using ets(), auto.arima(), Arima(), arima(), ar(), HoltWinters() and
>   StructTS().
>
> There is also a method for a ts object. If a time series
>   object is passed as the first argument to forecast(), the function will
>   produce forecasts based on the exponential smoothing algorithm of
>   Section 2.
>
> In most cases, there is an existing predict() function
>   which is intended to do much the same thing. Unfortunately, the
>   resulting objects from the predict() function contain different
>   information in each case and so it is not possible to build generic
>   functions (such as plot() and summary()) for the results. So, instead,
>   forecast() acts as a wrapper to predict(), and packages the
>   information obtained in a common format (the forecast class). We also
>   define a default predict() method which is used when no existing
>   predict() function exists, and calls the relevant forecast() function.
>   Thus, predict() methods parallel forecast() methods, but the latter
>   provide consistent output that is more usable.

Try the following.

```
fit <- auto.arima(sensor,D=1)
LH.pred <- forecast(fit,h=30)
plot(LH.pred)
grid()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain why forecast function is much nicer than predict?

Comment: Can you explain what is D=1 in fit <- auto.arima(sensor,D=1)?. Can I achieve the above result by using predict?

Comment: As to `D=1`, look at the help page (`?auto.arima`). It tells you that `D` gives the order of seasonal differencing, which is one in this case. Apart from that, I would also be interested in why `forecast` is nicer than `predict`.

Comment: @Nandu: I see that you just asked for clarification about `forecast` and `predict` in a separate question. In this case, please link there so that answers will be posted there and not here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333296/rwhy-forecast-is-nicer-than-predict